# Missing packages: libx11-dev libxmu-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgl2ps-dev in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cocos2d-x

when I execute `./install-deps-linux.sh` in the path of `lee@ubuntu:~/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-2.2.5$`, I got errors like this:

```
Checking for missing packages ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libx11-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libxmu-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libglu1-mesa-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libgl2ps-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libxi-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libglfw-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libzip-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libfontconfig1-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libsqlite3-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libglew*-dev
Missing packages: libx11-dev libxmu-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgl2ps-dev libxi-dev libglfw-dev libzip-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfontconfig1-dev libsqlite3-dev libglew*-dev .
You may be asked for your password for package installation.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libx11-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxmu-dev
E: Unable to locate package libglu1-mesa-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgl2ps-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxi-dev
E: Unable to locate package libglfw-dev
E: Unable to locate package libzip-dev
E: Package 'libcurl4-gnutls-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libfontconfig1-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsqlite3-dev
E: Unable to locate package libglew*-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libglew*-dev'
```

I have no idea how to  resolve it，maybe I have to download relevant packages,but it seems that there is no correct resource on the internet,who can help me,I express my gratitude to you！！

Comment: We need the contents of `install-deps-linux.sh`.

Comment: Cocos2D-X v2.2.5 is 4 years old right now. I would recommend moving to a newer, v3.x version if possible. What version of Ubuntu are you running? (You can find out by typing `lsb_release -a` at the command line).

Comment: @MattSchuchard I believe he's using this script: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/af3c9747fafb0f9b3745637f3946bcfbd9a17025/install-deps-linux.sh (That's from the 2.2.5 tag of the Cocos2D-X repo)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in solving some of the issues if not all
On Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev
```